# Row to Column in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, row

I am trying to have a column vector in my for loop. It goes in as a column but goes out as row and that causes problem in the loop because I get the error

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape `(2,2)` into shape `(2,)`

Please help. Here how it goes:

I have an Xtrue value where the output is

```
Out[77]: 
array([[ 44.3161691],
   [-10.5871559]])
```

and then I go into the loop:

```
xk_1 = Xtrue #initialization before loop
n=103.789 #calculated under some other concept
t=int(float(np.floor(n)))-1 #number of iterations
for k in range(0,t,1):
       xk_1[:,k] = A.dot(xk_1[:,k-1]) + B.dot(U) #B.dot(U) is a standard value
```

the output of `B.dot(U)` is `(2,1)`

```
array([[-4.903325],
   [-9.80665 ]])

A=array([[1, 1],
   [0, 1]])
```

Here what comes out of `A.dot(xk_1[:,k-1])` with a shape `(2,)`:

```
array([ 35.15803805,  -9.87264348])
```

where it supposed to have the shape `(2,1)`

An important point here is that I need the kth value of the multiplication when it is `(2,k)` because that is how whole system works.

Answer (score 0):

`xk_1[:,k-1]` would be of shape `(2,)` so that's why `A.dot(xk_1[:,k-1])` is also `(2,)`. And then adding a `(2,)` to a `(2,1)` will result in a `(2,2)`, hence the error.

You can always change a row vector `(k,)` to column vector `(k,1)` with:

```
my_array.shape = -1,1 # inplace
```

or

```
my_array.reshape((-1,1)) # returns a new array
```

(the `-1` stands for automatic detection of the dimension size, in your case, it is equivalent to `2`.)

Comment: Hello 
Thank you very much for your reply. I forgot to mention that I am trying to learn python by myself and I am only one month old. I am sorry but I did not understand how to apply what you wrote to my codes. However, I decided to transpose B.dot(U) (such as xk_1[:,k] = A.dot(xk_1[:,k-1]) + (B.dot(U)).T) and deal with the rows and columns at the end. But now I am receiving another error saying 'IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1' and now I cannot figure out why this comes out. I would really be happy if you could reply me again. Thank you very much

Comment: Hello again I just wanted to inform you that I corrected the code as: xk_1 = Xtrue.T t=int(float(np.floor(n)))
for k in range(1,t,Dt):
    xk_1[k,:] = A.dot(xk_1[k-1,:]) + (B.dot(U)).T  where Xtrue.T to turn everything into row matrix. I started loop from 1 (because of k-1) and changed indexing from [:,k] to [k,:] (since it is a row matrix now) but now I receive error saying 'IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1' I don't understand what axis it is talking about and why my index is wrong. It looks correct to me but hope there is an easy answer to that. Thank you again.

Comment: Well this is not a tutorial website. There are already tons of informations only to learn. I suggest you start reading the docs...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion